# Set of ImageButtons to Fill Available Space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

In my UI design I have a region of variable width (depending on display size and orientation). This region I would like to fill with a set of square `ImageButton`s with the following constraints

- buttons fill the entire width of the area and adapt automatically to different display orientations and widths
- exception: the buttons do not grow beyond a certain maximum size, and are left-aligned after that
- buttons are and remain square shape
- button images are rather large (300x300px) and should be scaled down to fill the buttons

For this I am using a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation as shown in below XML. The `LinearLayout` has `layout_height = wrap_content`, however it seems to stretch to its available height, resulting in the buttons not being square. Also, the `max_width` setting does not seem to have any effect.

How do I need to change the xml to get the desired layout?

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/layoutImageButtons">

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:maxWidth="50dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:id="@+id/imageButton1" />

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:maxWidth="50dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:id="@+id/imageButton2" />

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:maxWidth="50dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:maxWidth="50dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:id="@+id/imageButton4" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that `ImageButton`s don't handle keeping the aspect ratio of the image very well when they are resized. Alternatives are to create one's own button control and add the missing behavior or simply use `ImageViews` with `OnClickListeners` with the layout below.

Setting the enclosing `LinearLayout`'s width to `wrap_content` and enclosing it in another container such as `GridLayout` ensures that the images are left-aligned after reaching the maximum size.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layoutImages">

         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView3" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView4" />

    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

And, for completeness, the Java code:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView mImageView1;
    ImageView mImageView2;
    ImageView mImageView3;
    ImageView mImageView4;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        // ...

        mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
        mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
        mImageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
        mImageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView4);

        mImageView1.setClickable(true);
        mImageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });
        mImageView2.setClickable(true);
        mImageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });
        mImageView3.setClickable(true);
        mImageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });
        mImageView4.setClickable(true);
        mImageView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you that you should have different dimensions in values directory for different screen sizes for the `height` and `width` for the `ImageButton`.

I tried to make some changes to the layout which you can reconfigure as you require. Kindly notice, if you increase the `width` of the `ImageButton` irrespective to it's `height` it will become a `rectangle` from a `square`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very nicely documented answer. What's missing here for me is that the buttons are not using the available space, i.e. you solved this by adapting the spacing **between** the buttons to the available space.

Comment: OK, now I saw the description you added. I want the images to grow and keep the spacing small. So does this mean what I want to achieve can only be done in code and not in layout?

Comment: @jerry, give me some time, let me see if anything else can be done

Comment: @jerry, what is the maximum height do you want the ImageButton to take

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102808/discussion-between-pankaj-nimgade-and-jerry).